# Is It possible to show tooltip on dropdown in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my web application, i have dropdowncheckboxes control but i am trying to show tooltip on selectbox items.  Is is possible to do.

I am tried code:

.aspx:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Saplin.Controls" Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" TagPrefix="asp"  %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css" type="text/css" />
     <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    script tag
      <script>
             $(function () {
                 $("#tooltip1").tooltip();
             });
          </script>

        <div class="tooltip1"> <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server" UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="true"> <Style SelectBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="130" />
                        <Texts SelectBoxCaption="" />  
                                                 </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="tooltip1"></asp:Label>
```

.CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tooltip1.Text = dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption;
}
 protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    checkedList.Add(item.Value);
                }

            }            
            dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList.ToArray());
}
```

tooltip is not displayed can anyone tell me where i did mistake i don't know. Is there any events to display tooltip

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qpZB.png)

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to set the `ToolTip` property from your control? Your label "tooltip1" has this property. Set its value on your aspx or cs file.

Comment: hi,Thank you i tried your saying tooltip control but it not show any tooltip. can you see once i need to display tooltip on dropdown select box for selected items

Comment: Is this `asp:DropDownCheckBoxes` a custom control?

Comment: i am using Saplin.Controls because i need to display ok and cancel buttons in my dropdown. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have information about Saplin Controls. But If you can't find a `ToolTip` property, it's because Saplin controls don't allow you to do this directly. This way, you have to use `FindControl` method to search for an element where you can add your tooltip. Then you can add using `ToolTip` property or `yourElement.Attributes.Add("title", "your tooltip")`

Answer (score 0):

Following method is working for adding tooltip for lists

```
public static void BindTooltip(ListControl lc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lc.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            lc.Items[i].Attributes.Add("title", lc.Items[i].Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using Saplin.Controls of dropdowncheckboxes is it possible to work with your code

Comment: hi, can you please see this link my control taken from this site [link](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/dropdowncheckboxes-or-drop-down-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-1100.aspx)

Comment: Can anyone please provide me any solution to me i need it

Comment: I think it does not provide tooltip. You can take its source and modify as per following thread. http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/discussions/395133